# changing edge type and adding

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I'm new to tex, and am in the process of creating a flowchart. I've been able to build off of some templates I've found, but am stuck on modifying 3 features:

1. I would like the edge (line) to be "forked" rather than lines at an angle.
2. I want to put (curly) brackets that wrap around the end of the last column, but the edges I create jut out from the center of the last column instead of the right hand. There would be two such brackets, the first bracketing the first 8 boxes, and the second bracketing the last 8 boxes. I'd also like to put labels along the bracket saying "v1" or "v2."
3. Lastly, I want to get rid of the edges between v/X/Y/Z on the top of the line.

Below is the outcome I'd like:

[image]

And here's the current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{center}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
%%%>

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand*{\h}{\hspace{5pt}}% for indentation
\newcommand*{\hh}{\h\h}% double indentation
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \captionof{figure}{Flowchart}
  % setting the typeface to sans serif and the font size to small
  % the scope local to the environment
  \sffamily
  \footnotesize


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  %  level distance = 1.6cm,
  %  level 1/.style={sibling distance =3.5cm},
  %  level 2/.style = {sibling distane 1cm},
    block_title/.style ={rectangle, draw=none, thick, fill=white,
      text width=5em, text centered},
    block_assign/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=18em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
    block_lost/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=16em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
      line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=0pt}]
    % outlining the flowchart using the PGF/TikZ matrix funtion
          [edge from parent/.style= {thick, draw= cyan, edge from parent fork right},
         sibling distance=10em,level distance=6em,
      every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center},  grow=right]
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=25mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=15mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=7mm]
  \node[block_title]{v} [grow' =right, right]
   child{node[block_title] {X}
      child{node[block_title] {Y}
        child{node[block_title] {Z}}}
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}


  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    block_center/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=5em, text centered,
      %minimum height=4em, 
      },
    block_left/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=16em, text ragged, minimum height=4em, inner sep=6pt},
    block_noborder/.style ={rectangle, draw=none, thick, fill=none,
      text width=18em, text centered, minimum height=1em},
    block_assign/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=18em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
    block_lost/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=16em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
      line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=0pt}]

    % outlining the flowchart using the PGF/TikZ matrix funtion
    %      [edge from parent/.style= {thick, draw= cyan, edge from parent fork right},
    %      sibling distance=10em,level distance=6em,
    %  every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center},  grow=right]
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=25mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=12mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=6mm]


  \node[block_center]{V1} [grow' =right, right]
   child{node[block_center] {R}
      child{node[block_center] {111}
        child{node[block_center] (test1) {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
      child{node[block_center] {222}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
 %       child{node[block_center] {ut - White 2 (n=xx)}}
      }
   child{node[block_center] {G}
      child{node[block_center] (test2) {111}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
      child{node[block_center] {222}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] (test2) {B}}}
      };
      \draw[red] (test1) to [bend left = 30](test2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    block_center/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=5em, text centered,
      %minimum height=4em, 
      },
    block_left/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=16em, text ragged, minimum height=4em, inner sep=6pt},
    block_noborder/.style ={rectangle, draw=none, thick, fill=none,
      text width=18em, text centered, minimum height=1em},
    block_assign/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=18em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
    block_lost/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,
      text width=16em, text ragged, minimum height=3em, inner sep=6pt},
      line/.style ={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=0pt}]

    % outlining the flowchart using the PGF/TikZ matrix funtion
    %      [edge from parent/.style= {thick, draw= cyan, edge from parent fork right},
    %      sibling distance=10em,level distance=6em,
    %  every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center},  grow=right]
        \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=25mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=12mm]
        \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=6mm]


  \node[block_center]{V2} [grow' =right, right]
   child{node[block_center] {R}
      child{node[block_center] {111}
        child{node[block_center] (test1) {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
      child{node[block_center] {222}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
 %       child{node[block_center] {ut - White 2 (n=xx)}}
      }
   child{node[block_center] {G}
      child{node[block_center] (test2) {111}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] {B}}}
      child{node[block_center] {222}
        child{node[block_center] {A}}
        child{node[block_center] (test2) {B}}}
      };
      \draw[red] (test1) to [bend left = 30](test2);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**follow up question:**
The forest function looks great! I'm having an issue once I type longer texts in the boxes, the length of the boxes don't remain consistent and it messes up the lining of the trees.

How can I specify the size of the rectangles so that they are consistent across the different "sibling levels"?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm}, ultra thick, transform canvas={xshift=1mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{flowchart}
\medskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, minimum width=15mm}
[
    [Versions, for tree={no edge, draw}[R1[sequence number[R2]]]
    ]
    [V1, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [R[111[A, name=A1][B]][222[A][B]]]
        [G[111[A][B]][222222222222[A][B, name=B1]]]
    ]
    [V2, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [R[111[A, name=A2][B]][222[A][B]]]
        [G[111[A][B]][222222222222[A][B, name=B2]]]
    ]
]
\draw[mybrace] (A1.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V1}(B1.south east);
\draw[mybrace] (A2.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V2}(B2.south east);
\end{forest}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw[red] (test1.north east) to [bend left = 30](test2.south east);` You are loading the `forest` package but don't use it? It is much superior (and more intimidating) than TikZ' own `trees` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easier with `forest`. The braces are the trickiest part, and require the `decorations.pathreplacing` and  `calligraphy` libraries. I made a style `mybrace` for this purpose. Then they can be drawn using `\draw[mybrace]` along with the `name`s of the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}
\tikzset{mybrace/.style={decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm}, ultra thick, transform canvas={xshift=1mm}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east, minimum width=15mm}
[
    [V, for tree={no edge}[X[Y[Z]]]
    ]
    [V1, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [R[111[A, name=A1][B]][222[A][B]]]
        [G[111[A][B]][222[A][B, name=B1]]]
    ]
    [V2, no edge, for tree={forked edge, draw}
        [R[111[A, name=A2][B]][222[A][B]]]
        [G[111[A][B]][222[A][B, name=B2]]]
    ]
]
\draw[mybrace] (A1.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V1}(B1.south east);
\draw[mybrace] (A2.north east)--node[right=2mm]{V2}(B2.south east);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One follow up question. I'm trying to customize the forest code, and one issue I'm having issues with is that the length of the rectangle doesn't stay constant. As a result, I'm getting issues where the lines are messed up. I can't figure out a way to add an img and code here so I edited my original post. TIA!!

Comment: @ravman: In the future, it's better to ask a new question rather than change the original. You can add `tier/.pgfmath=level()` to the main  `for tree`, or you can increase `minimum width`.

Comment: Thank you! Will do.